# Excel Formula Shows 0 and not null

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using `VLOOKUP()` to populate a few cells, but when the value does not exist in the lookup table, I want the cell to show the original content, which is usually nothing.  However, when the cell has nothing in it, my formula returns a 0

Why is my formula returning a 0 instead of the original blank cell value (how to have it return the original cell value)?

```
=IF(K14<>"",VLOOKUP(K14,Sheet132!$A$2:$E$333,3,FALSE),K14)
```

Inputting this formula presents an error of, but clicking okay shows a 0?

> Careful we found one or more circular references in your workbook that might cause your formulas to calculate incorrectly

**EDIT**
I would even settle for the text of the `IF()` statement to be "Not In Lookup List" if I can get that to show something other than a 0

Comment: are you putting this formula into K14?  That is the only way this formula would be a circular formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how EXCEL behaves.  You can see the behaviour quite simple by:

1. make sure Cell `A1` is blank/empty.
2. put this formula into `B1`:  `=A1`
3. note how B1 shows a value of "0".
4. put this formula into `C1`:  `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)`

You can use that similar ISBLANK check in your original query.

`=IF(K14<>"",VLOOKUP(K14,Sheet132!$A$2:$E$333,3,FALSE),if(isblank(K14,"",K14)))`

### [edit]

Checking of the actual VLOOKUP is blank, however, means duplicating the VLOOKUP, which kinda sucks. So I usually drop it in it's own cell (let's say `L14`), you then have:

`L14: =VLOOKUP(K14,Sheet132!$A$2:$E$333,3,FALSE)`

and then your function above changes to:

`=if(ISERROR(L14),if(isblank(K14),"",K14),L14)`

Comment: I have never used the isblank() formula, so thank you not only for answer but also for the introduction to a new excel formula!!

Comment: No problem . I just added an additional note at the end ... might help, might not :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to this problem

1. use an if error in case vlookup fails, otherwise use vlookup
2. have the iferror output K14 if there is something there
3. else a blank if nothing in k14

original

- =IF(K14<>"",VLOOKUP(K14,Sheet132!$A$2:$E$333,3,FALSE),K14)

Modified

- =+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K14,Sheet132!$A$2:$E$333,3,FALSE),IF(K14="","",K14))